# Google Maps v3 API Markers doesn't work and leave a blank page

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make a custom map with markers.
I already got a custom map that work's but when i try to add a marker it results in a blank page.

i have no idea what im doing wrong because i did everything i should do, unless I missed something.

I used custom images that are public available 
my correct code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Nexoness Nation - Google Maps</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://maps.gstatic.com/favicon3.ico"/>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
       <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var customMapTypeOptions = {
           getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
                   var normalizedCoord = getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom);
                    if (!normalizedCoord) {
                      return null;
                    }
                    var bound = Math.pow(2, zoom);
                    /*Edit this URL to where you upload your tiles...*/
                    return "http://nexonessnation.bugs3.com/tile_" + zoom + "_" + normalizedCoord.x + "-" + normalizedCoord.y + ".svg";

           },
           tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
           isPng: true,
           maxZoom: 3,
           minZoom: 0,
           name: "Nexoness Nation"
         };

         var customMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(customMapTypeOptions);

            // Normalizes the coords that tiles repeat across the x axis (horizontally)
              // like the standard Google map tiles.
              function getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom) {
                var y = coord.y;
                var x = coord.x;

                // tile range in one direction range is dependent on zoom level
                // 0 = 1 tile, 1 = 2 tiles, 2 = 4 tiles, 3 = 8 tiles, etc
                var tileRange = 8 << zoom;

                // don't repeat across y-axis (vertically)
                if (y < 0 || y >= tileRange) {
                  return null;
                }

                // repeat across x-axis
                if (x < 0 || x >= tileRange) {
                  x = (x % tileRange + tileRange) % tileRange;
                }

                return {
                  x: x,
                  y: y
                };
              }

        function initialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
            var myOptions = {
              zoom: 1,
              center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                    mapTypeIds: ["Nexoness Nation"]
                  }
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            map.mapTypes.set('Nexoness Nation', customMapType);
            map.setMapTypeId('Nexoness Nation');
          }

function addMarkers() {
  var bounds = map.getBounds();
  var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
  var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
  var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
  var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(),
                                        southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random());
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: map_canvas
    });
  }
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Does anybody see what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please create a fiddle for your code.

Comment: Im sorry but what do you mean with fiddle? isnt that a music instrument? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiddle

Comment: No, go to this link: http://jsfiddle.net and put your relevant code there so that it's easy for people to look into your problem.

Comment: i dont know if i did it alright... http://jsfiddle.net/Y5E85/

Comment: I think you forgot to include the html and css part in it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y7Cxn/ like that? i dont have a css part....

Comment: You can refer this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Shreerang/kEcgc/light/ for example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/M2RD6/ like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID of your div ("**map-canvas**") in `<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>` does not match the id you indicate in your script: `map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("**map_canvas**"), myOptions);`

Also in the jsfiddle you provided, you need to select `no wrap - <in body>` instead of `onLoad` in the second dropdown on the left menu because you're calling your `initialize()` function in the onLoad of the body.

Update: indeed, I forgot about the markers. First the function `addMarkers()` wasn't called from `initialize()`. Also let's not forget to send the "map" as a parameter so we can use it in `addMarkers`.

Finally getBounds is available after the event `bounds_changed` is fired, we just need to add a listener on it to get the values.

Here is a jsfiddle that works:
http://jsfiddle.net/M2RD6/4/

Comment: thanks! the code works indeed but i dont see the marker?

Comment: thanks indeed! if i want to have it like https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple so with cordinates i just have to change the function and add (map)?

They are all over the place

Comment: Your markers are all over the place because of the for loop and the Math.random() method. From here you have everything to display the markers, now it is your business to put them where you want ;)

Comment: No problem, I also struggled in the past with the google maps api :)